# how to run uft scripts on particular machine using jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, ui-automation, hp-uft

In my company we need to execute uft scripts on Project Manager machine with out uft through the JENKINS.UFT script is copied in main server as well as JENKINS also.Manager will login into jenkins in his system,when he click on Build now in uft jon then uft starts executing the scripts on project manager system but when i run the build now option then it is executing on server itself,Please provide solution for this.

Sample Script:

```
Browser("name:=Login Screen").Page("title:=Login Screen").WebEdit("name:=userVO.userName").Set "Uname"
Browser("name:=Login Screen").Page("title:=Login Screen").WebEdit("name:=userVO.userPasscode").Set "password"
Browser("name:=Login Screen").Page("title:=Login Screen").WebButton("name:=Login").Click
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following things

1) Add your managers machine as the slave machine on jenkins

2) Install UFT on your managers machine (There is no alternative to this)

3) use the option "Restrict where this project can be run" option on jenkins job and provide the slave machine name under label expression.

Once you have the above three things you should be able to trigger jobs on your managers machine.

For more details check the below article

https://sumeetkushwah.com/2015/03/24/implementing-ci-using-jenkins-and-uft/